# Get the less count id's PandaCode as the output

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Please help me to resolve this issue
i want to get the less size `PandaCode` as the output and i have an `PandaCode`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 37860
    [1] => 37016
    [2] => 37013
    [3] => 38220
    [4] => 38420
    [5] => 38223
)
```

Each `PandaCode` code have multiple `id`s
for example `37860` have count(id)=3 like this each `Pandacode`have `id` with count of different values but i want to get the `PandaCode` which is having less count of `id` as the output

```
foreach($pandacode as $dealer_code){
$query="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `dealer_details` 
        WHERE `PandaCode` like '$dealer_code' and `Senttime` like '%$today%'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$size = $row['COUNT(id)'];
}
```

Comment: first of all, you have to put your query outside of for each and use where IN

Comment: @DsRaj: Then how we will get the count for each PandaCode

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your issue in right way than you to add whereIn instead of for each, try this

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as ids FROM `dealer_details` WHERE `PandaCode` IN ($pandacode) and `Senttime` like '%$today%' GROUP BY `PandaCode` ORDER BY ids ASC LIMIT 1
```